# How to prove that $ \lVert \Delta_q^{'}u\rVert_{L^p}\le C\lVert u\rVert_{L^p}$ is not true?

Tags: fourier-analysis, harmonic-functions

For $q\in \mathbb{Z}$,denote $$\Delta_q^{'} y:=1_{2^q\le |\xi|\le 2^{q+1}}\,(D)u$$
Prove that the inquality $$ \lVert \Delta_q^{'}u\rVert_{L^p}\le C\lVert u\rVert_{L^p}$$
for some constant $C$ independent of $q$ is false in the case $p\ne 2$.

The defination of operator $\chi(D)$ is following.
$$\chi (D)f:=\mathcal{F}^{-1}(\chi \mathcal{F(f)})$$
Hint:Try with the function $u=\chi$,$\chi$ is supported in the ball $\{\xi \in \mathbb{R}^N||\xi |\le \alpha\}$ ,and is a smooth function valued in $[0,1]$

My attempt:$$  \Delta_q^{'}u=(2\pi)^{-N}\int_{2^q\le |\xi|\le 2^{q+1}}e^{i\xi \cdot x}d\xi\int_{|y|\le \alpha}e^{-i\xi \cdot y}\chi(y)dy$$
In addition,we know that $\lVert\chi\rVert_p\le \infty$.My thought is to prove $\lVert \Delta'u\rVert_{L^p}$ is not bounded.

However,I don't know how to deal with it.

Comment: Could you please clarify what is $D$?

Comment: @popoolmicapo I have added some content.

Comment: How are you defining $\chi(D)$ in general since the Fourier transform is not trivially generalizable to $L^p$? Your definition works for $f \in L^1\cap L^p$.

Comment: Actually, I want to consider the question on Schwartz space.@CameronWilliams

Comment: Ah that'll work then!

Comment: What you can do is realize that the inner integral is rotation-invariant since $\chi$ is and is therefore a radial function. You can switch to hyperspherical coordinates (pick up a factor from the angular coordinates, it's not really important). Then since that function is radial, you can switch to hyperspherical coordinates for the $\xi$ integral and pull out the angular coordinates again since that function is also radial. So unless I'm mistaken, you end up with something like 

$$ \int_{2^q}^{2^{q+1}} e^{i r R} \int_0^{\alpha} e^{-i r y} \,y^{n-1}\,dy\, r^{n-1}\,dr.$$

Comment: Thank you!@CameronWilliams However,I still don't know how to use the expression to handle my question. Can you give me a hint?

Comment: @Mr.xue Try doing those integrals to see if you get a resultant function that is in $L^p$, I guess?